# How to get result from executive immediate (Advantage Data Architect)

Tags: t-sql, advantage-database-server

I create the same SQL script, which must count number of records in my table. I'm using dynamic sql.
For example:

> ```
> ...
> declare @myTableName string;
> declare @query sqtring;
> @myTableName = 'table_1';
>
> @query = 'select count(*) from ' + @myTableName;
> executive immediate(@query);
> ...
> ```

This query running good, but I don't know how can I get result from:

> executive immediate(@query);

I tried to find answer on the Internet, but I does not find answer.

May be anybody know answer on my question?

Thank.

Comment: I don't think you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to perform a `SELECT`. I think it's more intended to be used with DML (`ALTER`, 'INSERT`, and so forth); I don't know of any way to get it to return a rowset, because it pretty much does an ExecSQL. The documentation says "The prepared statement or script is freed immediately after execution.".

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank you for your answer.
I resolved my problem.
Initially, I need to get result from executive immediate(@query);
for insert to other table.
So I decided to use this result inside executive immediate and insert into my table.
Now my query looks like: 'q = (select count(*) from ' +@myTableName + '); insert into table_2 values (q);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a temporary table, this can be done like this:

```
DECLARE @IntVal Integer;
DECLARE @myTableName string;
DECLARE @query string;

CREATE TABLE #table1 (
  Value Integer
);

@myTableName = 'table_1';
@query = 'INSERT INTO #table1 (Value) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @myTableName;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @query;

@IntVal = (SELECT Value FROM #table1);
```